# How to block a specified script in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Is it possible to block the loading of a specified script (e.g. jquery) in Firefox and Chrome?

If not, is there an addon that can do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use any adblocker for this.

Comment: I bet there are tons of addons for that already. Answers on this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/278590/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-specific-js-script-from-a-specific-website) may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go in `Chrome Dev Tools -> Network` and select JS then reload the page. You'll see all the scripts, you can right click on a script to block it.

It's the same process in Firefox. `Firefox Dev tools -> Network` and select JS to find all scripts.

Comment: These blocks don't survive a browser restart. Do you know how to make them sticky?